# Python: plot multiple y axes in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, yaxis

I have tried to plot three graphs with different y axis in one plot. It works so far. The code for it is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.close('all')
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
        ax.set_frame_on(True)
         ax.patch.set_visible(False)
         for sp in ax.spines.values():
             sp.set_visible(False)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16, 9]
fig, host = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()
par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

p1, = host.plot(x1,y1, "g-", label = "y1", lw=0.5, alpha = 0.7)
p2, = par1.plot(x2,y2, "r-", label = "y2", lw= 0.5)
p3, = par2.plot(x3,y3, "b-", label = "y3", lw= 0.5)

host.set_xlabel("Time [s]")
host.set_ylabel("y1")
par1.set_ylabel("y2")
par2.set_ylabel("y3")

host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
par2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [p1, p2, p3]

host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
plt.title('Messung 1')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25))
host.grid(axis = 'x' ,linestyle = '-', linewidth='0.5')

plt.show()
```

[The plot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux4gO.png)

Everything works fine so far. But there is a mistake. The blue graph (y3) is wrong. This signal was measured at the same period of time as the other two signals, but according to the plot the signal ends at 290 seconds.
I found out, that always the last plotted signal is wrong.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: i believe in pyplot there is no time domain and each sample is viewed as time `t` meaning unless your inputs are the same length and align where you expect, the graph wont be correct and pyplot might try to scale.

Comment: This will all depend on the `x1`, `x2`, `x3`. Those are unknown to the reader of this question. Hence there is little one can help with here.

Comment: x1, x2, x3 have values between 0 and 360 seconds. Only the step size is different. x1 has a very small step size. x2 and x3 have the same step size and the step size is larger than the step size of x1.

Comment: I would recommend providing a [mcve] with mockup data defined inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

it's because plt.xticks() does not update all the twin-axes...

replace
`plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25))`

with
`host.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25)))`

and you're good to go ;-)

or alternatively use:

```
host.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25))
par1.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25))
par2.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)+100,25))
```

and by the way... simply adding the following lines provides a verifying example:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.linspace(1,100,100)
x2 = np.linspace(1,100,50)
x3 = np.linspace(1,100,50)

y1 = x1 
y2 = x2 **3
y3 = x3 **2
```